# setPadding() dosen't works when creating CardView dynamically

Tags: android, android-cardview

setPadding doesn't work in my code. It appears all the Cards are connected together the padding is not applied

```
card = new CardView(mContext);

            // Set the CardView layoutParams
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
card.setLayoutParams(params);

            //Set CardView Padding
card.setPadding(15,15,15,15);

            // Set CardView corner radius
card.setRadius(8);

            // Set cardView content padding
card.setContentPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this you can use  Set `cardView` content padding.

```
CardView card = new CardView(mContext);

                // Set the CardView layoutParams
                LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                );
                card.setLayoutParams(params);

                // Set CardView corner radius
                card.setRadius(10);

                // Set cardView content padding
                card.setContentPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);


                // Set the CardView maximum elevation
                card.setMaxCardElevation(15);

                // Set CardView elevation
                card.setCardElevation(10);
```

**EDIT**

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
params.setMargins(10, 10, 10,10);
```

Comment: I've already used setContentPadding....I need padding in between two different cards not between the card and its contents

Comment: you need margin i think  use this **params.setMargins(10, 10, 10,10);**

Comment: @ShrG I am glad Happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `card.setContentPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);` 
instead of `card.setPadding(15,15,15,15);`